# Android studio non-layout xml Graphic Editor

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that there's a design view for layout. Is there a design view for menu xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't one. You will have to make a menu in the same way as you would in Eclipse.

Comment: one more question, the values/strings also have no graphical editor?